# Arguments when Creating Functions

Tags: python

I am trying to create a function from weather data on a .csv file: When given temperature and a location, the function returns the number of entries that exceed that temperature in the specific location. After the condition statement I am unsure of what I need to write.
I have read the dictionary in a previous cell.

```
import csv

given_location = input ('Enter given location:')
given_temp = input('Enter given temp:')
count = 0

def daysOver (smalldict, location, temp):
    reader = csv.Dictreader(dataFile)
    for row in reader:
        if row ['Location'] == given_location and line['MaxTemp'] > given_temp:
            count = row
        return count
        print('Number of days over',given_temp, 'in', given_location,':', count)
```

Comment: Think of what `return` will do where you have it. It will stop the loop. There will be no more iterations -- there is only that first one. The `print` below it will never execute.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to replace `count = row` with count `count += 1`